# Активация поиска при получении значения из адресной строки

Tags: php, javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сделал заполнение `value` у `input[search]` через `<?php echo $search; ?>`
проблема в том что поиск выполняется `on.("keyup")` и из-за этого при загрузке страницы ничего не происходит, только если навести курсор и нажать любую кнопку.

как сделать так, что б при загрузке страницы сразу активировался поиск?

Comment: Вынесите алгоритм поиска в отдельную функцию и вызывайте её при загрузке страницы или onkeyup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
window.onload = function () {
    alert('Your code here');
};
```